# How to make a checkbox appear in a normal way (white background)?

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF form with a checkbox defined like this:

```
<Views:MyView Background="{DynamicResource MainBackground}">
    ...
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ResourceKeys:Switch.YesNoStyle}}">
        ...
    </Style>
    ...
    <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" 
        IsEnabled="False"  
        Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Style="{x:Null}" 
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</Views:MyView>
```

There is a problem - it is displayed with a gray background (even, if it is active), which is confusing for the user:

Unchecked checkbox: [image: Unchecked check box with gray background]

Checked checkbox: [image: Checked check box with gray background]

I want the background to be white.

Probable causes of the problem is either

1. the style `<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"` or
2. the background setting of the top-level container (`Background="{DynamicResource MainBackground}"`).

I tried to

1. add a name to the the `CheckBox` and
2. create a new style for that name.

This resulted in the code shown below and didn't help.

```
<Views:MyView Background="{DynamicResource MainBackground}">
    ...
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ResourceKeys:Switch.YesNoStyle}}">
        ...
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Name="MyCheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>

    ...
    <CheckBox 
        Name="MyCheckBox"
        Grid.Column="0" 
        IsEnabled="False"  
        Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Style="{x:Null}" 
        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</Views:MyView>
```

How can I change the background of that particular check box to white (so that it looks like any other active check box) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color in this case is probably set because of the disabled state of the control. You can try to remove *IsEnabled="false"* and use something like HitTest:

```
<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Style="{x:Null}" />
```

In this way the control will not process any user input, so it will be similar to disabled but with the normal style.

**EDIT**

In order to use the style you defined you have to give it a Key and use it on the checkbox:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}"
       x:Key="WhiteCheckBox">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
</Style>

<CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          Style="{StaticResource WhiteCheckBox}" />
```

Comment: No, the control is **not** disabled. If you click on it, it becomes checked.